# How to code these conditional statements in more elegant & scalable manner

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement

In my software, I need to decide the version of a feature based on 2 parameters. Eg.

```
Render version 1 -> if (param1 && param2) == true;
Render version 2 -> if (!param1 && !param2) == true;
Render version 3 -> if only param1 == true;
Render version 4 -> if only param2 == true;
```

So, to meet this requirement, I wrote a code which looks like this -

```
if(param1 && param2) //both are true {
    version = 1;
}
else if(!param1 && !param2) //both are false {
    version = 2;
}
else if(!param2) //Means param1 is true {
    version = 3;
}
else { //Means param2 is true
    version = 4;
}
```

There are definitely multiple ways to code this but I finalised this approach after trying out different approaches because this is the most readable code I could come up with. 
But this piece of code is definitely not scalable because -

1. Let say tomorrow we want to introduce new param called param3. Then
   the no. of checks will increase because of multiple possible
   combinations.
2. For this software, I am pretty much sure that we
   will have to accommodate new parameters in future.

Can there be any scalable & readable way to code these requirements?

Comment: Are yo usure that the if/else if cascade is correct ? Because if some test returns true, the next won't be evaluated at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Seems correct, doesn't it? I think it is desired that only one `if` body is visited

Comment: @Lino: mutual exclusiveness of the expressions must be guaranteed then.

Comment: What is the expected result with `param3`? Can you describe the pattern change generally as we add params?

Comment: Do you plan to increase versions as well?

Comment: @Yves Daoust, yes if/else if cascade is correct. So, order of conditions also matter in the given approach.

Comment: @ גלעד ברקן , @Nitin , there are multiple possibilities with the parameters coming in future. They may refer to a newer version or they may be needed as an extra check for existing version.

Comment: I wonder if this could be an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Could you please say more about how what you call feature "versions" differ, and their relationship to the parameters? What are the parameters and feature? (can be a general description)

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**
For a scalable solution define the versions for each parameter combination through a `Map`:

```
Map<List<Boolean>, Integer> paramsToVersion = Map.of(
        List.of(true, true), 1,
        List.of(false, false), 2,
        List.of(true, false), 3,
        List.of(false, true), 4);
```

Now finding the right version is a simple map lookup:

```
    version = paramsToVersion.get(List.of(param1, param2));
```

The way I initialized the map works since Java 9. In older Java versions it’s a little more wordy, but probably still worth doing. Even in Java 9 you need to use `Map.ofEntries` if you have 4 or more parameters (for 16 combinations), which is a little more wordy too.

**Original answer:**
My taste would be for nested `if`/`else` statements and only testing each parameter once:

```
    if (param1) {
        if (param2) {
            version = 1;
        } else {
            version = 3;
        }
    } else {
        if (param2) {
            version = 4;
        } else {
            version = 2;
        }
    }
```

But it scales poorly to many parameters.

Comment: I don't like the new solution because you will have to generate up to 2^k lists for k parameters. This is unreadable, and the expansion of the lists is error prone.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then I’m glad that I let my old solution stand here too. I suppose each has its place depending on requirements and circumstances. At least if you add 2^k lists and get a param value wrong, in Java 9 `Map.of` or `Map.ofEntries` will complain about the resulting duplicate kay so you know there’s an error and you need to fix it.

Comment: This kind of error can be spotted at a glance as the values appear explicitly. What I am referring to is how you expand "(tall and not fat) or old and green" without a mistake, and how you can read that back from the truth table.

Comment: @Ole V.V. Yes these are better solutions than mine but scalability concern is still there.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to enumerate all the possible combinations of Booleans, it's often simplest to convert them into a number:

```
//                            param1:   F  T  F  T
//                            param2;   F  F  T  T
static final int[] VERSIONS = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 1};

...
version = VERSIONS[(param1 ? 1:0) + (param2 ? 2:0)];
```

Comment: This is really clever, but far from being readable and expressive. For a developer that is new to this code, it might even result cryptic.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner agreed, but there are readable variants and/or ways to comment it.  I'm just leaving that to the OP, since I would like a more concrete example before suggesting a best way.

Comment: I think the answer would benefit from including a comment or an example showing how to extend this beyond two parameters; e.g. `(param3 ? 4:0) + (param4 ? 8:0) + ...`, as it may not be clear to some that you are treating the bool sequence as a bit string.

Comment: I'm not sure this passes either the scalable or readable stated requirements. Ok, it might be technically scalable but as we'd add to the list of ternary `if`s, the expression evaluating the index will very quickly get unreadable (to me it already is, which doesn't say much about me I guess :)

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that there is a way that would be more compact, readable and scalable at the same time.

You express the conditions as *minimized expressions*, which are compact and may have meaning (in particular, the irrelevant variables don't clutter them). But there is no systematism that you could exploit.

A quite systematic alternative could be truth tables, i.e. the explicit expansion of all combinations and the associated truth value (or version number), which can be very efficient in terms of running-time. But these have a size exponential in the number of variables and are not especially readable.

I am afraid there is no free lunch. Your current solution is excellent.

---

If you are after efficiency (i.e. avoiding the need to evaluate all expressions sequentially), then you can think of the truth table approach, but in the following way:

- declare an array of version numbers, with 2^n entries;
- use the code *just like you wrote*  to initialize all table entries; to achieve that, enumerate all integers in [0, 2^n) and use their binary representation;
- now for a query, form an integer index from the n input booleans and lookup the array.

Using the answer by Olevv, the table would be [2, 4, 3, 1]. A lookup would be like (false, true) => T[01b] = 4.

What matters is that the original set of expressions is still there in the code, for human reading. You can use it in an initialization function that will fill the array at run-time, and you can also use it to hard-code the table (and leave the code in comments; even better, leave the code that generates the hard-coded table).

Answer (score 4):

Your combinations of parameters is nothing more than a binary number (like `01100`) where the `0` indicates a `false` and the `1` a `true`.

So your version can be easily calculated by using all the combinations of ones and zeroes. Possible combinations with 2 input parameters are:

1. `11` -> both are `true`
2. `10` -> first is `true`, second is `false`
3. `01` -> first is `false`, second is `true`
4. `00` -> both are `false`

So with this knowledge I've come up with a quite scalable solution using a "bit mask" (nothing more than a number) and "bit operations":

```
public static int getVersion(boolean... params) {
    int length = params.length;
    int mask = (1 << length) - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(!params[i]) {
            mask &= ~(1 << length - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return mask + 1;
}
```

The most interesting line is probably this:

```
mask &= ~(1 << length - i - 1);
```

It does many things at once, I split it up. The part `length - i - 1` calculates the position of the "bit" inside the bit mask from the right (`0` based, like in arrays).

The next part: `1 << (length - i - 1)` shifts the number `1` the amount of positions to the left. So lets say we have a position of 3, then the result of the operation `1 << 2` (`2` is the third position) would be a binary number of the value `100`.

The `~` sign is a binary inverse, so all the bits are inverted, all `0` are turned to `1` and all `1` are turned to `0`. With the previous example the inverse of `100` would be `011`.

The last part: `mask &= n` is the same as `mask = mask & n` where `n` is the previously computed value `011`. This is nothing more than a binary AND, so all the same bits which are in `mask` and in `n` are kept, where as all others are discarded.

All in all, does this single line nothing more than remove the "bit" at a given position of the `mask` if the input parameter is `false`.

---

If the version numbers are not sequential from `1` to `4` then a version lookup table, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723570/5515060) may help you.

The whole code would need just a single adjustment in the last line:

```
return VERSIONS[mask];
```

Where your `VERSIONS` array consists of all the versions in order, but reversed. (index `0` of `VERSIONS` is where both parameters are false)

Comment: I don't really care about downvotes, but may the downvoter mention why? So I could improve the answer if needed

Comment: Very solid approach.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but this does look a bit convoluted so I wouldn't be surprised that someone thought it downvote-worthy. Part of it might be the negative logic; it might feel more natural to just set the value to zero to start with, and then set the bits as necessary. Also, I think you could make the `(1 << length - i - 1)` clearer by running the loop downwards, not up and then just have `(1 << i)`.

Comment: Even more so, does `int mask = length * 2 - 1;` work? If there are three items in the list, this gives `mask = 5`, and 5 is `0101` and I'm not sure how that's useful?

Comment: How is this readable (a stated requirement by the OP)? "Readable" to me would mean being able to easily follow how the set of params, and each individual one, contributes to the expression evaluating the version. I can't find a place like that in the code snippet. (I did not downvote.)

Answer (score 4):

I would have just gone with:

```
if (param1) {
    if (param2) {
    } else {
    }
} else {
    if (param2) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Kind of repetitive, but each condition is evaluated only once, and you can easily find the code that executes for any particular combination. Adding a 3rd parameter will, of course, double the code. But if there are any invalid combinations, you can leave those out which shortens the code. Or, if you want to throw an exception for them, it becomes fairly easy to see which combination you have missed. When the IF's become too long, you can bring the actual code out in methods:

```
if (param1) {
    if (param2) {
        method_12();
    } else {
        method_1();
    }
} else {
    if (param2) {
        method_2();
    } else {
        method_none();
    }
}
```

Thus your whole switching logic takes up a function of itself and the actual code for any combination is in another method. When you need to work with the code for a particular combination, you just look up the appropriate method. The big IF maze is then rarely looked at, and when it is, it contains only the IFs themselves and nothing else potentially distracting.